# Single Cloud Function to call 100+ local functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Hi have 100+ cloud functions and a completed app, control panel and marketing website. When testing, my client said that the site was slow. This was because of the cold start times on all these functions.

I’m not really interested in having a cron job that hits each function every minute as there are a lot, and as other posts suggest, they are not always going to work.

Last night I had an idea. I know it is slightly gross, but I want to know what the consequences (other than not being able to release individual functions) would be of having a single cloud function end point, that switches a parameter with the function name, that then calls the other local functions that are imported. This would mean that the single function would be slow the first time for some users, but then every other function would be fast, as the function would already be warm.

Unfortunately I need to do one of the above to improve performance until firebase release a feature like aws to allow paying to keep functions warm.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to entirely eliminate cold start times.  They will always exist in serverless environments - that's a matter of fact.  The best you can do is organize your code to minimize the cold start times.  Without seeing all your code and your specific benchmarks, there is no specific advice we can geive.

**The only thing that's in your control is to make sure that each function only loads the minimum amount of code at the global scope to run correctly.**  So, if your functions all load some code at the global scope that's unused, all those functions will pay an unnecessary cold start cost to load and run the code they don't use.

There are resources out there that will help you do that.  [Watch this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v3eG9xpzNXM) for more detail.

Comment: Thanks for you quick response. I have read and watched the videos produced by firebase and I believe that I am only importing what is minimally required to execute the function. 

I understand that cloud functions will have cold start times, and it is on me that I didn’t do more research about them and it has now caused issues at the end.  I am not unfortunately at the point of looking for work arounds and was curious as to what, if any consequences would be for doing the above. I am okay with some cold starts, just needed a high reduction. Again thanks for your response :) appreciate it.

Comment: Would just like to update: I moved all my functions to use this method and after single long wait time the entire rest of application was blazing fast. This method has worked very well for me :)